# What will be url for the archiva central repository?

Tags: maven, archiva

In an example how to configure apache archiva this code should be added to the settings.xml ..but the url is not working what to do ?

```
            <mirror>
        <id>archiva.central</id>
        <url>http://192.168.1.7:8081/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [archiva documentation](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.0/userguide/using-repository.html) `/internal/` points to the repository which is default configured to proxy the maven central repository. They use it with a trailing slash, maybe this helps you?

Is the URL accessible via web browser? Did you also add the repository to your POM?

Comment: The trailing slash didn't helped? Do you get an error message?